# Where are my Rasberry Pi-files located?

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian

I have a resberry pi 2, when I boot it up there is a file (index.html) on the desktop. If i Pop the memory card into my macbook, I get two partitions.

```
\boot
\recovery
```

I have browsed throught them but can't seem to find any desktop folders. Where are the files located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will be on a separate partition on the SD card.

Typically Raspberry Pi installations of Linux have a small FAT32 boot partition and the rest of the space is in an ext4 partition. Presumably your MacBook does not have any support for ext4 partitions but if you were to plugin this into a Linux laptop you should see both partitions and all your user files are (most probably) in `/home/pi`.

Comment: thanks! For any future visitors, it's possible to install fuse and ext2-extension for osx.